# In which version of MediaWiki came the feature 'page preview'?

Tags: mediawiki

We've MediaWiki 1.31.0 installed, but can't find the feature 'page preview', which is described here: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Page_Previews

On this feature-page there's no hint, in which version of MediaWiki this feature was implemented. Can anybody tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not core Mediawiki functionality, but implemented via an extension. See here for more information: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Popups

PS: 1.31.0 has known security issues, you should at least upgrade to 1.31.7